# Circles.m for Octave

Tags: octave

I am a beginner at Octave, and I have limited knowledge of Matlab. Here is what I am trying to do. I am trying to run this script:

```
%%% May 23, 2016
%%% Potential Fields for Robot Path Planning
%
%
% Initially proposed for real-time collision avoidance [Khatib 1986].  
% Hundreds of papers published on APF
% A potential field is a scalar function over the free space.
% To navigate, the robot applies a force proportional to the 
% negated gradient of the potential field.
% A navigation function is an ideal potential field 

clc
close all
clear 
%% Defining environment variables
startPos = [5,5];
goalPos = [90, 95];
obs1Pos = [50, 50];
obsRad = 10;
goalR = 0.2; % The radius of the goal
goalS = 20;  % The spread of attraction of the goal
obsS = 30;   % The spread of repulsion of the obstacle
alpha = 0.8; % Strength of attraction
beta = 0.6;  % Strength of repulsion


%% Carry out the Potential Field Math as follows: 

u = zeros(100, 100);
v = zeros(100, 100);
testu = zeros(100, 100);
testv = zeros(100, 100);


for x = 1:1:100
    for y = 1:1:100
        [uG, vG] = GoalDelta(x, y, goalPos(1), goalPos(2), goalR, goalS, alpha);
        [uO, vO] = ObsDelta(x, y, obs1Pos(2), obs1Pos(1), obsRad, obsS, beta);
        xnet = uG + uO;
        ynet = vG + vO;
        vspeed = sqrt(xnet^2 + ynet^2);
        theta = atan2(ynet,xnet);
        u(x,y) = vspeed*cos(theta);
        v(x,y) = vspeed*sin(theta);
%         hold on
        
    end
end
%%
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:1:100,1:1:100);
figure
quiver(X, Y, u, v, 3)


%% Defining the grid

% Plotting the obstacles
circles(obs1Pos(1),obs1Pos(2),obsRad, 'facecolor','red')
axis square

hold on % Plotting start position
circles(startPos(1),startPos(2),2, 'facecolor','green')

hold on % Plotting goal position
circles(goalPos(1),goalPos(2),2, 'facecolor','yellow')

%% Priting of the path
currentPos = startPos;
x = 0;

while sqrt((goalPos(1)-currentPos(1))^2 + (goalPos(2)-currentPos(2))^2) > 1
    tempPos = currentPos + [u(currentPos(1),currentPos(2)), v(currentPos(1),currentPos(2))]
    currentPos = round(tempPos)
    hold on
    plot(currentPos(1),currentPos(2),'-o', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'black')
    pause(0.5)
end
```

Here is GoalDelta.m:

```
% This function gives delX, delY of attraction caused by the goal point

dGoal = sqrt((gx-vx)^2 + (gy-vy)^2); % distance bw goal and current position
thetaG = atan2((gy-vy),(gx-vx));     % angle between goal and current position
% delXG = 0; delYG = 0;

if dGoal<goalR
    delXG = 0; delYG = 0;
elseif ((goalS + goalR) >= dGoal) && (dGoal >= goalR)
    delXG = alpha*(dGoal - goalR)*cos(thetaG);
    delYG = alpha*(dGoal - goalR)*sin(thetaG);
else
    delXG = alpha*goalS*cos(thetaG);
    delYG = alpha*goalS*sin(thetaG);
end

end
```

Here is ObsDelta.m:

```
% This function gives delX, delY of repulsion caused by the obstacle

inf = 10;
dObs = sqrt((ox-vx)^2 + (oy-vy)^2); % distance bw goal and current position
thetaO = atan2((oy-vy),(ox-vx));     % angle between goal and current position
% delXO = 0; delYO = 0;

if dObs<obsRad
    delXO = -(sign(cos(thetaO)))*inf;
    delYO = -(sign(sin(thetaO)))*inf;
elseif (dObs < (obsS + obsRad)) && (dObs>=obsRad)
    delXO = -beta*(obsS + obsRad - dObs)*cos(thetaO);
    delYO = -beta*(obsS + obsRad - dObs)*sin(thetaO);
else 
    delXO = 0;
    delYO = 0;
end

end
```

This is where I am getting the error
*>> circles

error: 'x' undefined near line 112, column 112
error: called from
circles at line 112 column 1*

This is Circles.m that this error comes from. From what I understand, this would not have this error in Matlab, but I cannot afford Matlab. Therefore, I have no way of knowing. In any case, I am trying to figure out how to solve this error.

```
function [ h ] = circles(x,y,r,varargin)
% h = circles(x,y,r,varargin) plots circles of radius r at points x and y. 
% x, y, and r can be scalars or N-D arrays.  
% 
% Chad Greene, March 2014. Updated August 2014. 
% University of Texas Institute for Geophysics. 
% 
%% Syntax 
%  circles(x,y,r)
%  circles(...,'points',numberOfPoints)
%  circles(...,'rotation',degreesRotation)
%  circles(...,'ColorProperty',ColorValue)
%  circles(...,'LineProperty',LineValue)
%  h = circles(...)
% 
%% Description
% 
% circles(x,y,r) plots circle(s) of radius or radii r centered at points given by 
% x and y.  Inputs x, y, and r may be any combination of scalar,
% vector, or 2D matrix, but dimensions of all nonscalar inputs must agree. 
% 
% circles(...,'points',numberOfPoints) allows specification of how many points to use 
% for the outline of each circle. Default value is 1000, but this may be
% increased to increase plotting resolution.  Or you may specify a small
% number (e.g. 4 to plot a square, 5 to plot a pentagon, etc.). 
% 
% circles(...,'rotation',degreesRotation) rotates the shape by a given
% degreesRotation, which can be a scalar or a matrix. This is useless for
% circles, but may be desired for polygons with a discernible number of corner points. 
% 
% circles(...,'ColorProperty',ColorValue) allows declaration of
% 'facecolor' or 'facealpha'
% as name-value pairs. Try declaring any fill property as name-value pairs. 
%
% circles(...,'LineProperty',LineValue) allows declaration of 'edgecolor', 
% 'linewidth', etc.
%
% h = circles(...) returns the handle(s) h of the plotted object(s). 
% 
% 
%% EXAMPLES: 
%
% Example 1: 
% circles(5,10,3)
% 
% % Example 2: 
% x = 2:7;
% y = [5,15,12,25,3,18]; 
% r = [3 4 5 5 7 3]; 
% figure
% circles(x,y,r)
% 
% % Example 3: 
% figure
% circles(1:10,5,2)
% 
% % Example 4: 
% figure
% circles(5,15,1:5,'facecolor','none')
% 
% % Example 5: 
% figure 
% circles(5,10,3,'facecolor','green')
% 
% % Example 6: 
% figure
% h = circles(5,10,3,'edgecolor',[.5 .2 .9])
% 
% % Example 7: 
% lat = repmat((10:-1:1)',1,10); 
% lon = repmat(1:10,10,1); 
% r = .4; 
% figure
% h1 = circles(lon,lat,r,'linewidth',4,'edgecolor','m','facecolor',[.6 .4 .8]);
% hold on;
% h2 = circles(1:.5:10,((1:.5:10).^2)/10,.12,'edgecolor','k','facecolor','none');
% axis equal 
% 
% % Example 8: Circles have corners
% This script approximates circles with 1000 points. If all those points
% are too complex for your Pentium-II, you can reduce the number of points
% used to make each circle.  If 1000 points is not high enough resolution,
% you can increase the number of points.  Or if you'd like to draw
% triangles or squares, or pentagons, you can significantly reduce the
% number of points. Let's try drawing a stop sign: 
% 
% figure
% h = circles(1,1,10,'points',8,'color','red'); 
% axis equal
% % and we see that our stop sign needs to be rotated a little bit, so we'll
% % delete the one we drew and try again: 
% delete(h)
% h = circles(1,1,10,'points',8,'color','red','rot',45/2); 
% text(1,1,'STOP','fontname','helvetica CY',...
%     'horizontalalignment','center','fontsize',140,...
%     'color','w','fontweight','bold')
% 
% figure
% circles([1 3 5],2,1,'points',4,'rot',[0 45 35])
% 
%
% TIPS: 
% 1. Include the name-value pair 'facecolor','none' to draw outlines
% (non-filled) circles. 
% 
% 2. Follow the circles command with axis equal to fix distorted circles. 
%
% See also: fill, patch, and scatter. 

%% Check inputs: 

assert(isnumeric(x),'Input x must be numeric.') 
assert(isnumeric(y),'Input y must be numeric.') 
assert(isnumeric(r),'Input r must be numeric.') 

if ~isscalar(x) && ~isscalar(y)
    assert(numel(x)==numel(y),'If neither x nor y is a scalar, their dimensions must match.')
end
if ~isscalar(x) && ~isscalar(r)
    assert(numel(x)==numel(r),'If neither x nor r is a scalar, their dimensions must match.')
end
if ~isscalar(r) && ~isscalar(y)
    assert(numel(r)==numel(y),'If neither y nor r is a scalar, their dimensions must match.')
end

%% Parse inputs: 

% Define number of points per circle: 
tmp = strcmpi(varargin,'points')|strcmpi(varargin,'NOP')|strcmpi(varargin,'corners')|...
    strncmpi(varargin,'vert',4); 
if any(tmp)
    NOP = varargin{find(tmp)+1}; 
    tmp(find(tmp)+1)=1; 
    varargin = varargin(~tmp); 
else
    NOP = 1000; % 1000 points on periphery by default 
end

% Define rotation
tmp = strncmpi(varargin,'rot',3);
if any(tmp)
    rotation = varargin{find(tmp)+1}; 
    assert(isnumeric(rotation)==1,'Rotation must be numeric.')
    rotation = rotation*pi/180; % converts to radians
    tmp(find(tmp)+1)=1; 
    varargin = varargin(~tmp); 
else
    rotation = 0; % no rotation by default.
end

% Be forgiving if the user enters "color" instead of "facecolor"
tmp = strcmpi(varargin,'color');
if any(tmp)
    varargin{tmp} = 'facecolor'; 
end

%% Begin operations:

% Make inputs column vectors: 
x = x(:); 
y = y(:);
r = r(:); 
rotation = rotation(:); 

% Determine how many circles to plot: 
numcircles = max([length(x) length(y) length(r) length(rotation)]); 

% Create redundant arrays to make the plotting loop easy: 
if length(x)<numcircles
    x(1:numcircles) = x; 
end

if length(y)<numcircles
    y(1:numcircles) = y; 
end

if length(r)<numcircles
    r(1:numcircles) = r; 
end

if length(rotation)<numcircles
    rotation(1:numcircles) = rotation; 
end

% Define an independent variable for drawing circle(s):
t = 2*pi/NOP*(1:NOP); 

% Query original hold state:
holdState = ishold; 
hold on; 

% Preallocate object handle: 
h = NaN(size(x)); 

% Plot circles singly: 
for n = 1:numcircles
    h(n) = fill(x(n)+r(n).*cos(t+rotation(n)), y(n)+r(n).*sin(t+rotation(n)),'',varargin{:});
end

% Return to original hold state: 
if ~holdState
    hold off
end

% Delete object handles if not requested by user: 
if nargout==0 
    clear h 
end

end
```

Comment: I guess this one shows why you get an error in the other question. `circles` needs to start with a line `function h = circles(x,y,r,varargin)`.

Comment: I corrected what circles.m looks like. `function h = circles(x,y,r,varargin)` is at the beginning of circles.m

Comment: Wait, in your two questions you show the same code, but different error messages?

Comment: Indeed. I am not sure why I am getting multiple errors.